# Can the existence of a period be used to differentiate between a directory and file?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

I want to be able to determine if a path is a file or a directory. All I can get is their names because i'm using dirent.h in c and it does not support entry->d_type for some reason. For cross platform linux / windows, can I just check if the name contains a period or not to see if it's a file or not?

Comment: Of course it's possible to detect a difference between a file and a directory (as exist on a filesystem) in a cross-ish platform nature. If your code doesn't, fix it.

Comment: `man 3 stat`  `man 7 stat.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (struct dirent)->d_type to work, it depends on the implementation and support on underlying file system you are using. If this is not supported in the file system it would not work.

Refer to the [man](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html)

```
unsigned char d_type

    This is the type of the file, possibly unknown. The following constants are defined for its value:

    DT_UNKNOWN

        The type is unknown. Only some filesystems have full support to return the type of the file, others might always return this value.
```

Answer (score 2):

No; filenames can have periods, as can directory names, but neither has to.